# How to backup the contents of an S3 Bucket locally using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created this function to pull objects from my S3 Bucket. It works but because of the -Key parameter I can only do one file at a time.

Is there anyway to back up the entire contents of the bucket without writing multiple Copy-S3Object cmdlets?

```
function CopyFromS3ToFolder($S3_Bucket, $S3_Folder_Destination, $S3_Key, $S3_SecretKey, $S3_AccessKey, $S3_Region)
{
    #http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html (Amazon Simple Storage Service)
    #version AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-2.0.11.0-ps-2.0.11.0-tk-1.6.5.2    

    Write-Host "Copying from S3 to Local Directory"
    Write-Host "Folder Name :$S3_Folder_Destination"         
    Copy-S3Object -BucketName $S3_Bucket -LocalFile $S3_Folder_Destination -SecretKey $S3_SecretKey -AccessKey $S3_AccessKey -Region $S3_Region -Key $S3_Key
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objects = Get-S3Object -bucketname $S3_Bucket  -SecretKey $S3_SecretKey -AccessKey $S3_AccessKey -Region $S3_Region -KeyPrefix 8.9.2014

foreach($key in $objects.key)
    {
        $filename = $key -replace "8.9.2014/"
        Copy-S3Object -Bucket $S3_Bucket -Key $key "$S3_Folder_Destination\$filename" -SecretKey $S3_SecretKey -AccessKey $S3_AccessKey -Region $S3_Region
    }
```

see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=441291

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Get-S3Object` to get the keys you want, and then pipe that to `Copy-S3Object`, something like below:

```
Get-S3Object -bucketname "Bucket1" | %{ Copy-S3Object -Key $_.key -LocalFile "path" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work when I bind them to a file. e.g.

`%{ Copy-S3Object -Key $_.key -LocalFile $S3_Folder_Destination/test.txt`

@manojlds In the documentation it states that Copy-S3Object must download the object to a file. Is there anyway to just get the complete object itself instead of shoving it into a file? 

Thanks Conner

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html?page=Copy-S3Object.html&tocid=Copy-S3Object

For reference